# How to change images source Windows Store App with code

Tags: c#, .net, image, hover, windows-store-apps

I have 6 images on MainPage and I am using them as buttons. All images have their hover images, here I want to do; when I'm press down to image its source need to change(set its source to hover image) and when press up change its source again then navigate to other page.
I did that on Windows phone 8 easily but on Windows store app its really hard to do.
There are samples on the internet but no one of them useful for me and they have very long xaml codes, btw winrt toolbox dont work either. thanks

edit:

I found solution
there is a minor different between WP8 and WinStore app

in Wp8 using:

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets\\Common_Pic\\image1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

in Windows store :

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Common_Pic/image2.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: i'm sorry, forget to say. C#

Comment: So us what would you do so far ?

Comment: Muhammad Umar, sorry i dont understand what you say. i want to learn simplest way to change image dynamically with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the build action of the image to Content? Also if you specify the entire path using ms-appx then you don't need to add UriKind.Absolute. Just check if removing that works for you.

If you need the button's image to change when it is pressed/released, did you try writing this code in the PointerPressed/PointerReleased event?

I see you mentioned that the winrtxamltoolkit does not work for you but did you try the ImageToggleButton control in it which has many states(such as pressed/hover/checked/normal)?

Comment: My Pleasure :) Can you please let me know which solution you used though?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution in this page and it totally work for me.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/load-image-dynamically-from-application-uri-in-windows-store/

Hope it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ViewModel, you can add a property (ImageURL) with INotifyPropertyChanged implelemetation. Than you can add in xaml

```
<Image Source="{Binding ViewModel.ImageULR}"/>
```

And after you chage the image URL in the ViewModel, the image will chaged.